# Android like dialog on Angular/Html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making an Angular 1 app where there will be 2 button ignore and reject, I want to flash 2 different messages on the screen for a few seconds and then disappear automatically whenever the user presses them indicating that some info has just been ignored or rejected, kind of like a dialog in android apps. I don't know how to achieve it, any help would be welcome.

PS: I am using Zurb Foundation for styling if it includes some built-in feature that would be awesome!

Comment: Providing a minimal example at least in form of images/gif/link which demonstrates such functionality inside android app would help.

Comment: Check [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)